# Telerik MVC Grid Batch Editing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik-grid

Why wont my changes persist to db after I click save.

Product Repository:

```
public class ProductRepository
{
    NorthwindDataContext context = new NorthwindDataContext();

    public IList<EditableProduct> All()
    {
        return (from product in context.Products
                select new EditableProduct { 
                    ProductID = product.ProductID,
                    ProductName = product.ProductName,
                    UnitPrice = product.UnitPrice.HasValue ? product.UnitPrice.Value : default(decimal),
                    UnitsInStock = product.UnitsInStock.HasValue ? product.UnitsInStock.Value : default(int),
                    Discontinued = product.Discontinued,
                    LastSupply = DateTime.Today
                }).ToList();
    }

    public EditableProduct One(Func<EditableProduct, bool> predicate)
    {
        return All().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public void Update(EditableProduct product)
    {
        EditableProduct target = One(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID);

        if (target != null)
        {
            target.ProductName = product.ProductName;
            target.UnitPrice = product.UnitPrice;
            target.UnitsInStock = product.UnitsInStock;
            target.Discontinued = product.Discontinued;
            target.LastSupply = product.LastSupply;
        }
    }

    public void Insert(EditableProduct product)
    {
        product.ProductID = All().OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductID).First().ProductID + 1;
        All().Insert(0, product);
    }

    public void Delete(EditableProduct product)
    {
        EditableProduct target = One(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID);
        if (target != null)
        {
            All().Remove(target);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public partial class GridController : Controller
{
    ProductRepository productRepository = new ProductRepository();

    public ActionResult EditingBatch()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult _SelectBatchEditing()
    {
        return View(new GridModel(productRepository.All()));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult _SaveBatchEditing([Bind(Prefix = "inserted")]IEnumerable<EditableProduct> insertProducts,
        [Bind(Prefix = "updated")]IEnumerable<EditableProduct> updatedProducts,
        [Bind(Prefix = "deleted")]IEnumerable<EditableProduct> deletedProducts)
    {
        if (insertProducts != null)
        {
            foreach (var product in insertProducts)
            {
                productRepository.Insert(product);
            }
        }
        if (updatedProducts != null)
        {
            foreach (var product in updatedProducts)
            {
                var target = productRepository.One(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID);
                if (target != null)
                {
                    target.ProductName = product.ProductName;
                    target.UnitPrice = product.UnitPrice;
                    target.UnitsInStock = product.UnitsInStock;
                    target.LastSupply = product.LastSupply;
                    target.Discontinued = product.Discontinued;

                    productRepository.Update(target);
                }
            }
        }
        if (deletedProducts != null)
        {
            foreach (var product in deletedProducts)
            {
                productRepository.Delete(product);
            }
        }
        return View(new GridModel(productRepository.All()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using the code from our sample application which indeed does not update the database. It merely updates the data in memory so every single user browsing the demos sees only his changes.

To make it work you need to update the database. The actual implementation depends on the framework you are using for data access. For example for Linq To SQL you should use the `SubmitChanges` method. You can check [this](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/using-dropdownlist-to-edit-a-foreign-key-column.aspx) code library project which updates the underlying database.